# Crashes when 'sizeWithAttributes' is using

Tags: ios8, nsstring, size, nsattributedstring

I have the below code in my `ios7` project to measure the size of a `string` with particular font and size,

```
CGSize size = [someText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"uthmani" size:23.0f]}];
```

but it crashes with the below message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
>   objects[0]'

Please help some one, thanks.

Comment: Check the value of `[UIFont fontWithName:@"uthmani" size:23.0f]`.

Comment: @Larme: checked... why it is 'null'?

Comment: Because it seems to not have been correctly added to your project and seems to be a custom font. Check how add custom font.

Answer (score 2):

```
 CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(maxTextWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX);
 CGRect textRect = [str boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                        options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:messageTextSize]}
                                                        context:nil];

 CGSize messageSize = textRect.size;
```

try with this hope it will be useful